# Make Bootable Partiton on Grub of Windows Installation in Linux

Tags: boot-partition

I want to make a bootable partition on Linux and format it to NTFS for say 8 GB and run a software that I can put a Windows 7 or 10 on it and loaded it to grub and install windows.

1. Make Bootable Partition 8 GB NTFS OR FAT32?
2. Extract a ISO Image to the partition
3. Load the parition to GRUB 2
   some how make it bootable to load the Windows Files.
4. is it possible?

And what steps can I do to take action on doing it because I can talk about it but there is a lot of stuff online I can't find it very strange because I go to Google and it seems it not searching what I am asking?